# About Plotting a not-so-simple function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I define

```
b[w_, t_] := Sin[t w]/(4 π Cosh[t/2])
c[w_, t_] := Cos[t w]/(4 π Cosh[t/2])

a[1, w_] := Integrate[b[w, t], {t, 0, Infinity}]
a[2, w_] := Integrate[c[w, t], {t, 0, Infinity}]

M[w_] := a[1, w]^2 + a[2, w]^2
F[w_] := Sqrt[1 + 4 M[w] (1 + e^{-2 π w})^2]
```

and finally

```
λ[w_] := (1 + F[w])/(2 (1 + e^{-2 π w}))
```

I want to plot λ[w] for w on the real line but even asking

```
Plot[λ[w], {w, 7, 10}]
```

gives an empty picture. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `b[w_, t_] = Sin[t w]/(4 \[Pi] Cosh[t/2]);
c[w_, t_] = Cos[t w]/(4 \[Pi] Cosh[t/2]);

a[1, w_] = Integrate[b[w, t], {t, 0, Infinity}];
a[2, w_] = Integrate[c[w, t], {t, 0, Infinity}];

M[w_] = a[1, w]^2 + a[2, w]^2;
F[w_] = Sqrt[1 + 4 M[w] (1 + E^{-2 \[Pi] w})^2];
\[Lambda][w_] = (1 + F[w])/(2 (1 + E^{-2 \[Pi] w}));
Plot[\[Lambda][w], {w, 7, 10}]`

Comment: @cvgmt. `E^{-2 π w}` needs to  `E^(-2 π w)`

Answer (score 4):

There is a several syntax errors in your code. After their elimination one gets the following code

```
b[w_, t_] := Sin[t w]/(4 Pi Cosh[t/2]);
c[w_, t_] := Cos[t w]/(4 Pi Cosh[t/2])

a1[w_] := 
 Integrate[b[w, t], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> w \[Element] Reals]
a2[w_] := 
 Integrate[c[w, t], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> w \[Element] Reals]

M[w_] := a1[w]^2 + a2[w]^2;
F[w_] := Sqrt[1 + 4 M[w] (1 + Exp[-2 Pi w])^2];



L[w_] := (1 + F[w])/(2 (1 + Exp[-2 Pi w]))
Plot[L[w], {w, 7, 10}]
```

yielding the plot:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I recommend that you define `L` using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` so that the most time-consuming operations are done only once.

Comment: @Alexei Boulbitch Well, thank you very much, I was with your help finally able to draw the curve of $L$ for $w\in (-10, 20)$, but it took more than 30 minutes.

Comment: @Bob Harlon Thx. How does that affect the code above?

Comment: Evaluate `Clear[L]; ` Then change `:=` ([`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html)) to `=` ([`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)) in its definition. Execute the revised definition (should take about 15 seconds). The `Plot` should then evaluate in under a second.

Comment: @Bob Harlon Thanks a lot for your nice suggestion about Set. Your time predictions were correct and this is great!